# typescript cannot cast to generic type variable

Tags: typescript, redux

I want to create a generic function to create actions in typescript-redux.

What I want is to use a function passing an interface as the type variable. So I'm starting with this function :

```
function action<F>(type: string, payload: any): F {
    return { type, payload };
}
```

I want To use it like this :

```
interface Login {
    type: LOGIN_REQUEST;
    payload: credentials;
}

const Login = (credentials: Credentials) 
     => action<Login>(LOGIN_REQUEST, credentials);
```

The problem is that is have this error :

```
Type '{ type: string; payload: any; }' is not assignable to type 'F'.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `action` is generic there really is no way for the compiler to know that the object literal `{ type: string; payload: any; }` will satisfy the type `F`. This code would also be a valid call:

```
action<{ type: string; payload: any; otherMandatoryProp: boolean }>(LOGIN_REQUEST, credentials);
```

`F` in the above case has extra fields that `action` will not fill.

The simplest solution is to break out of the type safety sandbox in this case and use a type assertion:

```
function action<F>(type: string, payload: any): F {
    return { type, payload } as any;
}
```

This version would still allow a call with `{ type: string; payload: any; otherMandatoryProp: boolean }` which may cause some people to make some assumptions about what fields are on the retuned object. If you want to restrict `F` to types with just `type` and `payload` you can use a type constraint that specifies that the properties `type` and `payload` exist on `F` and if any other properties exist they are of type `never`:

```
function action<F extends { type : string, payload : any} & { [P in Exclude<keyof F, 'type' | 'payload'>]: never }>(type: string, payload: any): F {
    return { type, payload } as any;
}
const Login = (credentials: credentials) => action<Login>(LOGIN_REQUEST, credentials);
action<{ type: string; payload: any; otherMandatoryProp: boolean }>(LOGIN_REQUEST, {}) // invalid call
```

Comment: I tried with the type assertion ( {type, payload} as F) but it results in error : {type: string; payload: any} cannot be converted to type 'F'

Comment: @CTaque The call site will be type safe, the return will be of type `F`. At declaration site (where we `return  ... as any`) it will not be safe as this is inherently unsafe, as we can generally pass in derived types that have more properties, even the trick we use ensure calls with extra fields are invalid will not satisfy the compiler that the object literal is actually sufficient to satisfy type `F`

Answer (score 2):

Because you won't return any value, but only `Login`, you need to add a constraint:

```
function action<F extends Login>(type: string, payload: any): F {
    return { type, payload } as F;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

The typescript return value should match the object that you are returning 
It Should be of type login( or you can set it to any)

```
function action<F>(type: string, payload: any): Login  {
    return { type, payload };
}
```

Comment: This way it can't be a generic function. I want to be able to use it with any interface, typechecking the returned value